# Docker tmpfs volume and increasing size

Tags: docker, volume, docker-machine

I am starting a jenkins container like this, from a local repository:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /home/docker:/var/jenkins_home 192.168.99.101:5000/jenkins
```

the output of my container filesystem is like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none             19G  3.7G   14G  22% /
tmpfs           499M     0  499M   0% /dev
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           499M     0  499M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           897M  801M   97M  90% /var/jenkins_home
/dev/sda1        19G  3.7G   14G  22% /etc/hosts
```

As can be seen, /var/jenkins_home is getting full. How can I increase the size of "tmpfs"?

Answer (score 1):

When you start the container, folder `/var/jenkins_home` is mounted from your local host's `/home/docker`, as below option:

```
-v /home/docker:/var/jenkins_home
```

So if you clean the space in `localhost:/home/docker`, you will get more available space.

Comment: actually, I now try to point to my local drive /c/Users/... but since I am getting some "renaming" errors on Jenkins, I would assume there is some permission setting I need to verify?

Comment: i have solved this by below command docker-machine  stop myvm2
VBoxManage modifyvm myvm2 --cpus 2
VBoxManage modifyvm myvm2 --memory 4096